# Basic Access Query Combine Data

Tags: database, ms-access

I have 2 access tables.

Table A is a list of companies (Customer ID and Company Name)
Table B is a list of locations with a Customer ID column that references Table A

I need to write a query that takes the Customer ID from table B finds that Customer ID in Table A and then writes the Company Name field for that row back to a column in Table B.

Comment: Hi & welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of these links please:  [tour] and [mcve].  Specifically the bit that says _"Include details about what you have tried"_.  You're much more likely to get help if you've made an attempt first - otherwise the question will likely be closed.

Comment: You're also probably more likely to want a query which will return the most up to date company name each time - writing the name back to Table B will duplicate the data across tables and you could end up with mismatched data - e.g. Table A says it's Marks & Spencers while Table B says it's Sainsburys.

Comment: Agree with Darren. Do not save company name into TableB, just the CustomerID. Company name is retrieved in query linking tables.